# Run code only on div that has parent id of =

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get this code to run on the div "flow-hold" that has the parent name "holder1" and not on any of the other divs that have the same name.

```js
$('.flow-hold').each(function() {
  if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 50 && ($(this).text()) <= 600) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");

  } else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 601 && ($(this).text()) <= 1000) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");

  } else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 1001 && ($(this).text()) <= 4000) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");

  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flow-hold">100</div>
<div class="flow-hold">500</div>
<div class="holder1">
  <div class="flow-hold">1000</div>
</div>
<div class="holder2">
  <div class="flow-hold">3000</div>
  <div class="flow-hold">5000</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider assigning `parseInt($(this).text())` to a variable.  That would grealy simplify your code, because you could then write, `if (flow >= 50 && flow <= 600) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('.holder1 > .flow-hold')`. This will select all the direct children of `.holder` with `.flow-hold`:

```js
$('.holder1 > .flow-hold').each(function(){
  if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 50 && ($(this).text()) <= 600){
    $(this).css("background-color","green");
  }   
  else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 601 && ($(this).text()) <= 1000) {
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
  }
  else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 1001 && ($(this).text()) <= 4000) {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
  }   
  else {    
    $(this).css("background-color","transparent");
    }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flow-hold">100</div>
<div class="flow-hold">500</div>
<div class="holder1">
<div class="flow-hold">1000</div>
</div>
<div class="holder2">
<div class="flow-hold">3000</div>
<div class="flow-hold">5000</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your selector to `$('.holder1 > .flow-hold').each(...)` if the `.flow-hold` element needs to be a **direct** child of `.holder1`.

```js
$('.holder1 > .flow-hold').each(function(idx, el) {
  var amount = parseInt($(el).text());
  
  if ( amount >= 50 && amount <= 600) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");

  } else if (amount >= 601 && amount <= 1000) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");

  } else if (amount >= 1001 && amount <= 4000) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");

  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flow-hold">100</div>
<div class="flow-hold">500</div>
<div class="holder1">
  <div class="flow-hold">1000</div>
</div>
<div class="holder2">
  <div class="flow-hold">3000</div>
  <div class="flow-hold">5000</div>
</div>
```

**Otherwise**, use `$('.holder1 .flow-hold').each(...)` if the `.flow-hold` element can be a descendant (direct or not) of `.holder1`.

```js
$('.holder1 .flow-hold').each(function(idx, el) {
   var amount = parseInt($(el).text());
  
  if ( amount >= 50 && amount <= 600) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");

  } else if (amount >= 601 && amount <= 1000) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");

  } else if (amount >= 1001 && amount <= 4000) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");

  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flow-hold">100</div>
<div class="flow-hold">500</div>
<div class="holder1">
  <div class="intermediate">
    <div class="flow-hold">1000</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="holder2">
  <div class="flow-hold">3000</div>
  <div class="flow-hold">5000</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector

```
$('.holder1 .flow-hold').each(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('.flow-hold')` use **`$("parentSelector").find("childSelector")`** like:

```js
const colors = {
  50: "transparent",
  600: "green",
  1000: "yellow",
  4000: "red"
};

$(".holder1").find('.flow-hold').css("background-color", function() {
  const n = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
  return colors[Object.keys(colors).find(v=>n<=v)];
});
```

```html
<div class="flow-hold">100</div>
<div class="flow-hold">500</div>
<div class="holder1">
  <div class="flow-hold">1000</div>
</div>
<div class="holder2">
  <div class="flow-hold">3000</div>
  <div class="flow-hold">5000</div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```